# Apple Pay In App Provisioning -Add to wallet

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, wallet, mastercard

Using Apple Test card, I was able to add card in the SandBox environment. However, if I try to check the the status using `canAddPaymentPassWithPrimaryAccountIdentifier`; it is always returning `true`. Please advise.

Below is the code for the same:

```
 PKPassLibrary *passLibrary = [PKPassLibrary new];
 NSString * cardNumber = @"533636xxxxxx6636";    //16 digit card number
 [passLibrary          canAddPaymentPassWithPrimaryAccountIdentifier:cardNumber]
```

Comment: That method takes a `primaryAcountIdentifier`, not the PAN itself. As it's said in the docs `A unique identifier for the underlying funding primary account number (PAN). Note: This is not the PAN itself.` Hope it helps

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? Lack of documentation on this subject drive me insane.